# send one or zero with checkbox click in JS

Tags: javascript, php

I currently have a form with a loop that builds multiple checkboxes where I can successfully trigger an event.

I have my code set so that if the value from the database for the row is 1 then pre-check the box, which works.

I'm trying to make it so that when the box is checked, Javascript sends a '1' but if it's unchecked then it sends a '0'.

If the page loads with the database value of 1, and the box is checked, then when the user unchecks it I want it to send '0' to the console log and vice versa

```
<form id="saveLineup">
@foreach($list as $lists)
    <tr style="text-align:center;">
      <td><input class="addToLineup" type="checkbox" <?php if ($lists['LINE_UP'] == 1) echo "checked='checked'"; ?></td>
    </tr>        
@endforeach
</form>
```

currently, no matter what, the checkbox triggers the value 'on' to show on console.log, whether I check or uncheck it.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(".addToLineup").click(function (e) {

  updatedata.lineup = $(".addToLineup").val();

  console.log(updatedata);
});
```

Comment: You need `updatedata.lineup = $(this).val();` so you only check the clicked one, not the first of all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="saveLineup">
@foreach($list as $lists)
  <tr style="text-align:center;">
    <td>
      <input class="addToLineup" type="checkbox"/>
    </td>
  </tr>        
@endforeach
</form>
```

Edit: After clarification, you simply need a check for status of the checkbox when it's clicked, then send 1 or 0 based on that:

```
$(".addToLineup").click(function(e) {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    updatedata.lineup = 1;
  } else {
    updatedata.lineup = 0;
  }
  console.log(updatedata);
});
```

JSFiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/1agLdu5e/1

Comment: That does log the '1' but when I uncheck it it still logs '1'. So it's never logging 0

Comment: Right. You can add a check to your `if` statement where if `checked`, it's 1, otherwise 0. However, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this code... You're updating what seems to be a global variable (or outside of that scope) based on an array of checkboxes. See Barmar's answer; maybe he's got the right idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok, I'm really just trying to make sure that whatever checkbox is checked/unchecked will send either 1 or 0 to ajax call later

Comment: Hmm... The catch is that an unchecked checkbox is **not** sent to the server in an AJAX or `POST` call, so if you're setting all of these values to `1`, you'll just get a bunch of 1s being sent, but no 0s.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that. Even if I have the act of checking/uncecking triggering the call itself?

Comment: If you set the values to the ID of the current line, then it'll send those ID to the server if they're checked, like `[1, 5, 6, 8, 9, ...]`.

Comment: I'm basically trying to make it so that someone can check it and it updates the database with a 1 or if they uncheck it with a zero

Comment: Ok, so you don't need to send an array of data?

Comment: No, basically if they check/uncheck then I want the corresponding value sent in that immediate call. I've set it up so that clicking the box triggers the call to toggle the database values

Comment: Ok, then all we need is a check for whether or not the checkbox is checked or not when you click it. The value is either irrelevant, or it should be the `ID` of the line; up to you.

Comment: I guess it's irrelevent then. I basically just want to send a 1 or 0 corresponding to whether it's checked or not. If checking it triggers the call then send a 1, if unchecking triggers it then send 0

Comment: Now even with your update, can i keep the php check in the input? I need to make sure that if the value is 1 coming into page load that it's already checked

Comment: Yes of course; the PHP is handled before your HTML renders, and simply sets the initial state of your checkbox. I simply removed it for brevity.

Comment: Trying it  now and it says updateData is not defined now?

Comment: Oh sorry, `updatedata`; I used the wrong case (`updateData`)

Comment: jeez I should have caught that haha

Comment: Perfect that got it! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. Note, it can be more efficient, like `updatedata.lineup = $(this).is(":checked");` (which will be `true` or `false`), or more readable, like the answer I posted. Up to you though.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the values of the checkboxes to something that identifies the particular lineup. Then use an array-style name for the input. The result will be that `$_POST['addToLineup']` will be an array of all the identifiers.

```
<form id="saveLineup">
@foreach($list as $lists)
    <tr style="text-align:center;">
      <td><input class="addToLineup" name="addToLineup[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $lists['ID']; ?>" <?php if ($lists['LINE_UP'] == 1) echo "checked='checked'"; ?></td>
    </tr>        
@endforeach
</form>
```

Replace `'ID'` with the actual name of the table column containing the lineup ID.

Comment: Should `class="addToLineup[]"` be `class="addToLineup" name="addToLineup[]"`?

Comment: Correct, I fixed it.